# Code blocks: A debugging check in this application has failed (loss of precision)

Tags: c++, debugging, codeblocks

I keep getting the following error after running my code

[The debugger has failed error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDc5c.png)

The weird thing is no matter what I do to the code I keep getting the same error. For example, I commented out the packages and the defined function V_trap

[Commented out half the code and still get the same error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LyNM.png)

Furthermore, before this error, I get the cmd prompt with the previous result from the first run.

Even if I try doing a simple hello world code I get the same error

[Hello World, same error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaH77.png)

This error started yesterday, I am not sure what happened. I was trying to look at how to make a normal distribution in c++ yesterday.

I have already tried reinstalling code blocks, but the error still persists.

Comment: If you click "Stop" you can walk the call stack and see what code triggers it instead of guessing.